# How to make the font size larger in an input element when using Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with several inputs that is styled using Bootstrap.

I need to set the font size of the text input fields to something larger than usual (say 32px). This is larger than the font size that comes by default with bootstrap's `input-lg`.

I tried changing the font-size in the `input-lg` class in CSS but nothing changes.

What's the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 6):

Font size 32px is really big for an input. 
I assume `input-lg` is the class name for that input field, so to do that
add this on your css :

```
.input-lg {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

or

```
input {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

**Update**

Regarding the best way to achieve it, you must set a class name for that specific input field so it won't affect other fields.

e.g.

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="username-field input-lg" />
```

**css**

```
.username-field {
  font-size: 32px
}
```